# Same UITableViewCell when using JSON

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, uitableview

When my UITableview loads I am getting the same cell over and over. I'm assuming I need to add something about indexpath.row but this is my first time using JSON so I'm not sure exactly how to do it. Attached is my code

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"RemedyYouTubeTableViewCell";
    RemedyYouTubeTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];


    // Configure the cell...
    if (cell == nil) {
        NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"RemedyYouTubeTableViewCell" owner:nil options:nil];
        for(id obj in topLevelObjects) {
            if([obj isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]]) {
                cell = obj;
                break;
            }
        }


    }


    NSArray *subArray = [subDict objectForKey:@"items"];
    if ([subArray count]) {
        for (NSDictionary *dictItem in subArray) {
            cell.titleLabel.text = [dictItem objectForKey:@"title"];

            NSNumber *totalSeconds = [dictItem objectForKey:@"duration"];
            int *minutes = totalSeconds.intValue/60;
            int *seconds = totalSeconds.intValue%60;
            NSString *finalDuration =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%im %is", minutes,seconds];
            cell.durationLabel.text = finalDuration;


            NSString *separatorString = @"T";
            NSString *firstUploadString = [dictItem objectForKey:@"uploaded"];
            NSString *uploadString = [firstUploadString componentsSeparatedByString:separatorString].firstObject;
            cell.dateUploadLabel.text = uploadString;

            NSString *viewCount = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[dictItem objectForKey:@"viewCount"]];
            cell.viewsLabel.text = viewCount;

            NSDictionary *playBackDict = [dictItem objectForKey:@"player"];
            NSString *playBackURL = [playBackDict objectForKey:@"mobile"];
            NSLog(playBackURL);

            NSDictionary *thumbnailDict = [dictItem objectForKey:@"thumbnail"];

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

                NSString *thumbnailURL = [thumbnailDict objectForKey:@"sqDefault"];
                NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:thumbnailURL];
                NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
                UIImage *thumbNailImage = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];

                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                    // Here in main thread set image to your cell imageView.
                    // e.g.
                    [cell.videoThumbnail setImage:thumbNailImage];
                });
            });                
         };
     }

     return cell;
}
```

I'm just having trouble iterating through these so any help would be awesome. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are iterating over the `subArray` variable and configuring your cell for each item in the array. So all your cells always are going to have the same data that it correspondes with the last item of your array.

You need to use the indexPath parameters that receive in the `(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` to get the correct object for each cell, similar to this snippet:

```
(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{     
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"RemedyYouTubeTableViewCell";
    RemedyYouTubeTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    // Configure the cell... if (cell == nil) { 
    NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"RemedyYouTubeTableViewCell" owner:nil options:nil];
    for(id obj in topLevelObjects) { 
        if([obj isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]]) { 
            cell = obj; 
            break;
        }
    }

    NSArray *subArray = [subDict objectForKey:@"items"];
    // You should check here the array size before get the item
    NSDictionary *dictItem = [subArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    NSNumber *totalSeconds = [dictItem objectForKey:@"duration"];
    int *minutes = totalSeconds.intValue/60;
    int *seconds = totalSeconds.intValue%60;
    NSString *finalDuration =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%im %is", minutes,seconds];
    cell.durationLabel.text = finalDuration;

    // ToDo: all your configuration here using dictItem

    return cell;
}
```

`(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` is called for the tableView one time for each row depending on the value returned by `(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView` and `(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section`